Map() not rendering when in a list view
I have a list where I display trips and for each trip in the list I am trying to show a rendered map of the trip via my MapTripSnapshotView which works fine on it's own or initiated directly outside a list but when in a List {...} it does not work.  I get the little blue image (see pic)  I'm guessing that the list is not waiting for the map to render.  How would I go about addressing this so my list items show the rendered map for each list item when the list items are displayed?  I am using iOS17 and Map() via MapKit.
List {
    ForEach(tripSummariesSD.sorted(by: { $0.originationTimestamp < $1.originationTimestamp }) , id: \.self) { trip in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Trip: \(formatDateStampDayMonthTime(trip.originationTimestamp))")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.bottom, 1)
                        
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                 Text("fr: \(trip.originationAddress)")
                 Text("to: \(trip.destinationAddress)")
                 }
                 .font(.system(size: 14, design: .monospaced))
                        
                 MapTripSnapshotView(tripTimestamp: trip.originationTimestamp)
                            .frame(height: 200)


Any suggestions on how to address would be appreciated.
I outside a list show the MapTripSnapshotView works just fine via say a button click or in a VStack as an item.  But when in a list item it doesn't show.  All I get is the blue graphic generated by the system.

When something greedily takes space (like Map does), if it's inside another ScrollView, (like List), you must give it an explicit size. Otherwise, it collapses to nothing.

a Map inside a List works well, as mentioned give your MapTripSnapshotView a frame, eg:
.frame(width:333, height: 333)

I added width to the frame but sill a no show with the little graphic.  If I leave the view that has the list and go to another tab in my app and come back then it appears that time around.  It seems to be an issue when the view first loads?

have you tried adding height as well?

MapTripSnapshotView(tripTimestamp: trip.originationTimestamp)                             .frame(width: 200, height: 200) and still get the little blue image

All works well in my tests, the Map is displayed in a List when a frame is added. To find the cause of your problem,
show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code.  Show just enough code to replicate your issue when we compile and run it. You probably have some other code, eg NavigationSplitView or such, that is affecting the Map display.

Yes, its under a NavigationStack and TabView
'            NavigationStack {
TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
TripsViewV2()
.tabItem {
Image(systemName: "map")
Text("TripsV2")
}
}
.toolbar {
`

TabView should be top most, with NavigationStack inside. Show the code that produces your issue when we run it.

fyi you can't use id: \.self must be a real keypath to the unique identifier of the struct

I have my fancy side menu and nav all keyed into the stack.  I'll have to try a version with that stripped down. Not sure about how to handle the id: \.self will have to sort that out too.  Grrr.  Will take a few days to get a chance to try all this.  Will cycle back.

After some testing here is where I am.  If I generate the map in the list directly 'Map()' It brings up a rendered map.  If I have the Map() in a view re: 'MapTripSnapshotView(tripTimestamp: trip.originationTimestamp)
.frame(height: 200)' it get the blue image.  There's something about using the view in the list that causes the problem.  I hate to move all my logic up into the list.  Any suggestions?
